# How can we run two threads paralleling?

Tags: c#

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var myThread = new TestThread();
        Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(myThread.PrintName));
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(myThread.PrintType));
        t.Start();
        t1.Start();
        Console.Read();
    }
}

public class TestThread
{
    public void PrintName()
    {
        for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name {0}", i);
        }
    }

    public void PrintType()
    {
        for (int i = 100; i <= 180; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type {0}", i);
        }
    }
}
```

Here How can i fixed it show that i can generate output in sequential i.e 
first output of Name then only output of Type... Also I want to know about using Lock() in threads? where can i get good example. I am beginners in threading and need v.simple example.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mgold/MultithreadingIntro10062005000439AM/MultithreadingIntro.aspx)

There are multiple other articles, just google for 'introduction threading c#'.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose of threads is to allow things to happen at the same time. If you want things to happen one after another (i.e. sequentially), then do not use threads:

```
var obj = new TestThread();      
obj.PrintName();
obj.PrintType();
Console.Read();
```

Or put PrintName and PrintType into the same thread, in order to keep the UI responsive:

```
var myThread = new TestThread();
Thread t = new Thread(new ThreadStart(
    () => { 
        myThread.PrintName(); myThread.PrintType();
    } 
));
t.Start();
// Do things in the UI meanwhile
for (i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine("UI thread {0}", i);
}
Console.Read();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var myThread = new TestThread();
var x=Task.Factory.StartNew(() => myThread.PrintName());
x.ContinueWith(p => PrintType());
x.Wait();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//This will run two operation in sequence.   
public class TestThread
{
    public object obj = new object();
    public void PrintName()
    {
        Monitor.Enter(obj);
        for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Name {0}", i);
        }
        Monitor.Exit(obj);
    }

    public void PrintType()
    {
        Monitor.Enter(obj);
        for (int i = 100; i <= 180; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Type {0}", i);
        }
        Monitor.Exit(obj);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That will do the trick, you should read carefully and try to do it with 3 loops by yourself:

```
private static void SimpleLockTest()
        {
            Task[] myTasks = new Task[2];
            myTasks[0] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                LockTestThreadOne();
            });
            myTasks[1] = Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
            {
                LockTestThreadTwo();
            });
            Task.WaitAll(myTasks);
            Console.WriteLine("Done, press ENTER to quit");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        private static object locker = new object();
        private static void LockTestThreadOne()
        {
            Monitor.Enter(locker);
            for (int i = 1; i <= 50; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Name {0}", i);
                Monitor.Pulse(locker);
                Monitor.Wait(locker);                    
            }
            Monitor.Exit(locker);            
        }

        private static void LockTestThreadTwo()
        {
            Monitor.Enter(locker);
            for (int i = 100; i <= 180; i++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Type {0}", i);
                Monitor.Pulse(locker);
                Monitor.Wait(locker, 10);                    
            }
            Monitor.Exit(locker);
        }
```